# how to create a summary matrix of values, for dummy variables, and their combination

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `pandas` data frame:

```
    import pandas as pd

       df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy_1' : [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                          'dummy_2' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                          'dummy_3' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})
```

What I would to have in the end, is a "type of correlation matrix", but instead of correlations, having "how many `ones (1s)` each other variable has, for the `ones (1s)` of every variable.

So in my example the matrix should look like this

```
        dummy_1 dummy_2 dummy_3
dummy_1   2/6     1/6     0/6
dummy_2           4/6     2/6
dummy_3                   3/6
```

This matrix, is symmetrical, that's why I wrote only the upper diagonal elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy_1': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'dummy_2': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   'dummy_3': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]})


result = pd.DataFrame(df.T.dot(df) / len(df), columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
          dummy_1   dummy_2   dummy_3
dummy_1  0.333333  0.166667  0.000000
dummy_2  0.166667  0.666667  0.333333
dummy_3  0.000000  0.333333  0.500000
```

Comment: is there a way to do the same, but instead of just the percentage, calculating a "weighted percentage" ?

Comment: You could compute the percentage and then multiply by the matrix of weights?

Comment: the weights would be on respondent level (so there would an extra 6x1 column with the weights)

Comment: I believe that you can use dot again on the percentage and the weights

Comment: I see. I think is best if you ask another question, is hard to answer trough comments. But if I understood correctly I think you need to multiply first each row by the weights and then do dot